# Reading JSON data for every view

Tags: objective-c, ios, json

I am very new to iOS development and am writing an app with multiple views, each view having a tableview.

For every view, I need to read a separate JSON URL and then display the results. All the tutorials that I have been checking for this read the data in ViewController.m, but since I have a separate URL for each view, can I generalize the code and write it somewhere else?

Also, I would like to put it in some place from where the data is loaded the most effectively, i.e. there is not much waiting period in my app when I click a button.

I am using the below link for reference: http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can make separate parser, model class for parsing separate json url. Then load the parsed data in each view load.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to have a separate parser class `iTemplateParser`

Then in other View Controller you can create the `iTemplateParser` object.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) iTemplateParser *templateData;

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    NSData *theData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:templateFileName ofType:@"json"]];
    self.templateData = [[iTemplateParser alloc] initWithTemplateData:[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:theData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil]];
}
```

Now in `iTemplateParser` you can define many functions as per your need.
E.g.

```
- (id)initWithTemplateData:(NSDictionary *)iDataDict;
- (CGRect)frameForTableView;
- (UIFont *)fontForTableView;
- (UIColor *)tableBackgroudColor;
```

etc.

Now this methods you can call in your `ViewController` to display UI components.

**Hope this will help you.**